# Typoscript - SQL content on sys_file failed

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

My setup :

- Typo3 6.2
- Tx_news 3.2

One of my news (news UID = 948) is linked with one of my internal page (page UID = 99) and I would like to display on it all the news which are related (in this case only 1 news, the #948), inside a block with title of the news, thumbnail and link to read it. What I did with Typoscript :

- Search in database all news with related link = 99. **(Ok, I made it)**
- Get the UID of this news (948) **(Ok, I made it)**
- Search into "sys_file_reference" table all the files UID related to this news (11681) **(Ok, I made it)**
- Search into "sys_file" table the URL of picture from its UID **(Impossible)**

I got with success the UID of the sys_file I need ( = the picture of the news) but when I query on the "sys_file" table, no datas.

```
[... Typoscript ... ]

10 = TEXT
10 {

    field = uid_local
    wrap = UID of picture to display : |

}

20 = CONTENT
20 {

table = sys_file
select {

    selectFields = identifier
    pidInList = 0
    where =  sys_file.uid= ###my_marker###
    markers.my_marker.field = uid_local

}
renderObj = COA
renderObj {

    10 = TEXT
    10.field = identifier
    10.wrap = URL of the news picture : |

}
}
```

Output of this code is :

> UID of picture to display : 11681
>
> URL of the news picture :

I tried multiple alternative : change pid, inject the uid_local value manually ... no way to get my URL ( = identifier column in database).

Do you have any idea to solve my issue ?
Thanks :)

---

**EDIT** : here is the last try I did and it works.

```
20 = FILES
20 {

    references.table = tx_news_domain_model_news
    references.uid = 948
    references.fieldName = fal_media

    renderObj = IMAGE
    renderObj.file.import.data = file:current:uid 
    renderObj.file.treatIdAsReference = 1 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it by hand. Let TYPO3 help you:

```
20 = FILES 
20 { 
  references { 
    table = tx_news_domain_model_news
    // use the news record uid:
    uid.data = current:originalUid // current:uid
    // or is it fal_media ?
    fieldName = media
  } 
  renderObj = IMAGE 
  renderObj {
    file { 
      import.data = file:current:uid 
      treatIdAsReference = 1 
      width = 150c 
      height = 150c 
    } 
    altText.data = file:current:alternative
    titleText.data = file:current:title
    params = class="menu-img" 
    stdWrap.typolink.parameter.field = uid
  } 
  // maxItems = 1 
}
```

If you really want the url to the original file: use the IMG_RESOURCE object without resizing.

Comment: Thanks for yout help - but I can't find a way to use your snippet. In my case what should i fill into "uid.data" and "import.data" ? Even if I fill it manually for testing with "948" (uid of the news) it doesn't work. Sorry.. I'm a typoscript beginner :(

Comment: `.data`is used to access a defined field, for immediate values just assign `uid = 948`

Comment: :( Doesn't work neither ! I edited my first topic to let you see the latest version of my code. I can't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: don't use `publicURL`!  If you want to work with a file: use the object (represented by the uid). the object has more information than the pure name!

Comment: Hum OK, right. By the way my code is now running OK with references.fieldName = "fal_media" instead of "media", as you had proposed. Many thanks for your support, TYPO3/Typoscript is really hard to learn.

Comment: you will learn it - until you will not need it any more in some (2-3?) major releases it is not used any more.